# How can you search for a question within a tag?

Tags: support, new-nav

both searchboxes appear to only be searching for additional tags

If I add "Packages vs. CDN" after the tag "javascript", my search is broken fake tags and no results are displayed..

Thanks for your help

[image]

Comment: The upper right search box is _actually_ for search. Yes, they both populate with a tag when on a custom tab, but that's because you are searching for questions with (or without) certain tags. This could, and really should, be made more clear.

Comment: thank you that does appear to be working for me, though I would have expected a better implementation from SO

Comment: This feature is still alpha, so mistakes will be made/corrected as the team goes with this. I feel like this one is just one, kinda large, mistake. :)